# How to manipulate a data.frame by factor with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(a=factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3) ), b=c(1,1, 10,10, 20,20) )

  a  b
1 1  1
2 1  1
3 2 10
4 2 10
5 3 20
6 3 20
```

I want to split the data frame by column a, calculate b/sum(b) in each group, and put the result in column c. With plyr I can do:

```
fun <- function(x){
  x$c=x$b/sum(x$b)
  x
} 
ddply(df, .(a), fun )
```

and have

```
  a  b   c
1 1  1 0.5
2 1  1 0.5
3 2 10 0.5
4 2 10 0.5
5 3 20 0.5
6 3 20 0.5
```

but how can I do it with dplyr?

```
df %.% group_by(a) %.% do(fun)
```

returns a list instead of a data.frame.

Comment: I believe that that is simply how `do` works at the moment (returning a list of each piece). I seem to recall that changing this so that `do` stitches them back together was in the works as a change in the near future. You might try the dev version from github.

Comment: ...but for this particular example, I think all you need is `mutate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(c=b/sum(b))

  a  b   c
1 1  1 0.5
2 1  1 0.5
3 2 10 0.5
4 2 10 0.5
5 3 20 0.5
6 3 20 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a simplified example and my original df is a tbl produced by summarise() and has another column as group. That column causes some problem when using mutate. Is there a way to force re-group by 'a' other than as.data.frame()?

Comment: Can you update your question with a specific reproducible example? That would make it easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Just guessing here, but does [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653295/dplyr-issues-with-group-by?rq=1) address the issue you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention an R base solution, you can use `transform` (R base equivalent to `mutate`) and `ave` function to split vectors and apply functions.

```
> transform(df, c=ave(b,a, FUN= function(b) b/sum(b)))
  a  b   c
1 1  1 0.5
2 1  1 0.5
3 2 10 0.5
4 2 10 0.5
5 3 20 0.5
6 3 20 0.5
```