# Calculation of grouped zscores change the order

Tags: r, dplyr, scale

This question is based on [How do I calculate a grouped z score in R using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185816/how-do-i-calculate-a-grouped-z-score-in-r-using-dplyr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Here data are scaled (zscores) for different groups and ungrouped.

```
   dat = iris %>% 
      gather(variable, value, -Species) %>%
      group_by(Species, variable) %>% 
      mutate(z_score_group = (value - mean(value)) / sd(value)) %>%
      ungroup %>% 
      mutate(z_score_ungrouped = (value - mean(value)) / sd(value))
```

Scaling ungrouped preserves the order of the data.

```
> identical(order(dat$z_score_ungrouped), order(dat$value))
[1] TRUE
```

However, interestingly the data change their order by scaling group wise.

```
> identical(order(dat$z_score_group), order(dat$value))
[1] FALSE
```

In my opinion scaling should never change the order of data because this has a huge impact on rank based analysis (e.g. ROC-curves). Does anyone have an idea why grouping changes the order?

Comment: But when you scale using groups/subsets of data you're using a different `mean` and `sd`. Consider it as having a different baseline. That could lead to a a specific value to be large compared to a sub group, but not compared to the whole dataset. Consider normalising the sets {1,2,5}, {20,21,22} together and then separately and check what you get for value 5 for example.

Comment: Run this as an example 

`x1 = c(1,2,5);
x2 = c(20,21,22);
x = c(x1,x2);

(x1 - mean(x1)) / sd(x1);
(x2 - mean(x2)) / sd(x2);
(x - mean(x)) / sd(x)`

Comment: Ah, I see, you are totally right. The order is of course only preserved within and not across the groups. Thanks for clarifying