# tidyverse-dplyr summarise not operating as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

We're analyzing columns from our SQL Server environment. We're pulling column names and data types. Then we're running a simple pipe argument to see if we have mixed data types for the same column names across disparate tables.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF = data.frame(COLUMN_NAME = c("PARTYID","PARTYID","AGE","AGE","SALESID","SALES"), 
                DATA_TYPE = c("char","tinyint","int","smallint","varchar","numeric"))
DF %>% group_by(COLUMN_NAME) %>% 
           summarise(mixedTypes = (any(grepl("char", DATA_TYPE)) & 
                                  !(all(grepl("char", DATA_TYPE)))))
```

All I'm getting back is

```
  mixedTypes
1       TRUE
```

But I believe I should be getting back a subset of the data.frame, including both columns with a new column called `mixedTypes`.

UPDATE: Someone suggested using `conflicts` and I'm not educated enough to understand how to interpret the `detail=TRUE` output:

```
$.GlobalEnv
[1] "df"

$`package:forcats`
[1] "%>%" "%>%" "%>%" "%>%" "%>%"

$`package:purrr`
[1] "%>%"       "%>%"       "compact"   "%>%"       "%>%"       "set_names" "%>%"      

$`package:tidyr`
[1] "%>%"     "%>%"     "%>%"     "%>%"     "extract" "%>%"    

$`package:plyr`
 [1] "compact"     "arrange"     "count"       "desc"        "failwith"    "id"          "mutate"      "rename"      "summarise"  
[10] "summarize"   "is.discrete" "summarize"  

$`package:stringr`
[1] "%>%" "%>%" "%>%" "%>%" "%>%"

$`package:tibble`
 [1] "add_row"       "as_data_frame" "as_tibble"     "data_frame"    "data_frame_"   "frame_data"    "glimpse"       "lst"          
 [9] "lst_"          "tbl_sum"       "tibble"        "tribble"       "trunc_mat"     "type_sum"     

$`package:magrittr`
[1] "%>%"       "%>%"       "%>%"       "%>%"       "extract"   "set_names" "%>%"      

$`package:dplyr`
 [1] "%>%"           "%>%"           "%>%"           "%>%"           "%>%"           "add_row"       "arrange"       "as_data_frame"
 [9] "as_tibble"     "count"         "data_frame"    "data_frame_"   "desc"          "failwith"      "frame_data"    "glimpse"      
[17] "id"            "lst"           "lst_"          "mutate"        "rename"        "summarise"     "summarize"     "tbl_sum"      
[25] "tibble"        "tribble"       "trunc_mat"     "type_sum"      "src"           "summarize"     "coalesce"      "filter"       
[33] "lag"           "intersect"     "setdiff"       "setequal"      "union"        

$`package:Hmisc`
[1] "summarize"   "is.discrete" "src"         "summarize"   "format.pval" "units"      

$`package:ggplot2`
[1] "Position"

$`package:MyPackage`
[1] "coalesce" "HeatMap" 

$`package:stats`
[1] "df"     "filter" "lag"   

$`package:methods`
[1] "body<-"    "kronecker"

$`package:base`
 [1] "body<-"      "format.pval" "HeatMap"     "intersect"   "kronecker"   "Position"    "setdiff"     "setequal"    "union"      
[10] "units"
```

Comment: What version of dplyr are you using?

Comment: If i copy/paste the code above, that is not the result i'm getting. Have you tried this in a fresh R session? Anything suspicious in your `conflicts()`?

Comment: You're right. Fresh R session and it was fine. I don't know how to interpret the `conflicts()` output... there are multiple pipes (`%>%`) in `forcats`, `purrr`, `tidyr`, `stringr`, `magrittr`, and `dplyr`

Comment: Looks like `dplyr` 0.7.4

Comment: Looks you have both `package:plyr` and `package:dplyr` loaded which is usually not a good idea. But if you do need both of them, make sure to load `plyr` before `dplyr`.

Comment: Did you load **plyr** before **dplyr**?  If so, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with) is a possible duplicate.

Comment: plyr was being loaded in a function that was being called earlier in the script. It seems this call superseded the dplyr function. Flag this as a duplicate if you believe it so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the problem is that the `plyr` version of `summarise` is loaded after `dplyr` so when you call `summarise` you are getting the wrong one.  You should try to load `plyr` first (or much better, try not to load it at all), but you can also play safe by being explicit which version of `summarise` you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF = data.frame(COLUMN_NAME = c("PARTYID","PARTYID","AGE","AGE","SALESID","SALES"), 
                DATA_TYPE = c("char","tinyint","int","smallint","varchar","numeric"))

# bad:
DF %>% group_by(COLUMN_NAME) %>% 
  plyr::summarise(mixedTypes = (any(grepl("char", DATA_TYPE)) & 
                            !(all(grepl("char", DATA_TYPE)))))

# good:
DF %>% group_by(COLUMN_NAME) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mixedTypes = (any(grepl("char", DATA_TYPE)) & 
                            !(all(grepl("char", DATA_TYPE)))))
```

If you really need `plyr` loaded as well as `dplyr` it would be a good idea to do it this way, and also with other key conflicts like `mutate`.  But better is to avoid having both loaded at once.