# Why is dplyr collapsing my whole data frame and not grouping it

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been researching this for a while and I can't seem to find the issue.  I use dplyr regularly, but seems like all of a sudden, I am getting odd output from the group_by/summarise combination.

I have a large dataset and I am trying to summarize it using the following:

```
dataAgg <- dataRed %>% group_by(ClmNbr, SnapshotDay, Pre2016) %>%
  filter(SnapshotDay == '30'| SnapshotDay == '90') %>%
  summarise(
    NumFeat = sum(FeatureNbr),
    TotInc = sum(IncSnapshotDay),
    TotDelta = sum(InctoFinal),
    TotPaid = sum(FinalPaid)
  )
```

The setup of the data frame is below:

```
'data.frame':   123819 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ ClmNbr        : Factor w/ 33617 levels "14-00765132",..: 2162 2163 2163 2164 1842 2287 27 27 27 28 ...
 $ SnapshotDay   : Factor w/ 3 levels "7","30","90": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pre2016       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Post2016","Pre2016": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ FeatureNbr    : int  6 2 3 3 6 2 4 5 6 5 ...
 $ IncSnapshotDay: num  5000 77 5000 4500 77 2200 1800 1100 1800 25000 ...
 $ FinalPaid     : num  442 0 15000 5000 0 ...
 $ InctoFinal    : num  -4558 -77 10000 500 -77 ...
 $ TimeDelta     : num  25.833 2.833 2.833 0.833 1.833 ...
```

When I execute the code, I get 1 obs. of 4 variables; there is no grouping applied.

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ NumFeat : int 287071
 $ TotInc  : num NA
 $ TotDelta: num NA
 $ TotPaid : num 924636433
```

I used to do this all the time without problems.

I could use aggregate, but sometimes, I am mixing and matching functions based on the column so it does not always work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you have loaded [plyr before dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with/26933112#26933112)?

Comment: @aosmith: you meant `plyr` "after" `dplyr` right?

Comment: @Tung Yes, "after" is what might cause the problem. :-D

Comment: No, I am not using plyr at all; unless somehow it gets cached, but I frequently clean the global environment.

Comment: What does `sessioInfo()` show? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. A `str()` isn't as helpful as a `dput()` for testing.

Comment: Cleaning the global environment doesn't unload any packages.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a bit of research and some experimentation, the order of the library load matters.  The original order was the following:

```
library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(caret)
library(markovchain)
library(knitr)
library(Metrics)
library(RColorBrewer)
```

However, ggplot2 loads in plyr as a dependency, so in order to make this work more smoothly, the order should be revised to load `dplyr` last; which is what I used to do.

```
library(RODBC)
library(DT)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(caret)
library(markovchain)
library(knitr)
library(Metrics)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
```

Alternately, as in Python, it can be accomplished by specifying the library to execute the command. In Python, we import libraries in the following syntax:

```
import numpy as np
```

Then any `numpy commmands` are referenced using `np.` like `np.array()` the R syntax is the following `library::`

Adding `dplyr::` to the commands fixes the problem as shown below.

```
dataAgg <- dataRed %>% dplyr::group_by(ClmNbr, SnapshotDay, Pre2016) %>%
  dplyr::filter(SnapshotDay == '30'| SnapshotDay == '90') %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    NumFeat = sum(FeatureNbr),
    TotInc = sum(IncSnapshotDay),
    TotDelta = sum(InctoFinal),
    TotPaid = sum(FinalPaid)
  )
```

Comment: If you update to a more current version of `ggplot`, it won't attach `plyr` to your search path, it will just use it internally.

Comment: That was [changed in 2015](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/4a8b43531a4dd2c1c75b3f75629d494e14867ae5#diff-82aec99efe7f43b9727953d81800795c) ... I wonder what else could use upgrading?

Comment: Thanks for the information.  However, I did not set up the environment, and thought it was updated given that is R version 3.5.1.  It seems like it might make sense to merge a few of these packages (dplyr. plyr, ddply) to eliminate this issue.