# R Group by function used for grouping and summing values gives problem

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

Why does this piece of code:

```
letter = c("A","B","C","C","A")
product = c("Beef","Chicken","Beef","Beef","Beef")
value = c(10,20,40,10,5)
df <- data.frame(letter,product,value)

df1 = df %>% group_by(letter,product) %>% summarise(value = sum(value))
```

Results in this:

```
> df1
  value
1    85
```

Rather than this?

```
> df
  letter product value
1      A    Beef    15
2      B Chicken    20
3      C    Beef    50
```

Comment: [Why are my dplyr group_by & summarize not working properly? (name-collision with plyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with); [Why does summarize or mutate not work with group_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp)

Comment: Following the link provided by @Henrik, it looks like you have loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`. Here is what happened: `df %>% group_by(letter, product) %>% dplyr::summarise(value = sum(value))` and `df %>% group_by(letter, product) %>% plyr::summarise(value = sum(value))`

Comment: Thanks everyone! This solved my problem: df = df %>% group_by(letter,product) %>% dplyr::summarise(value = sum(value))

Comment: How should I handle this duplicate question?

Comment: @Afke I think you should just leave it as a signpost for the linked posts. Cheers