# group_by and sum a column using dplyr not giving the ecpected result

Tags: r

Where am I going wrong with this data.

I am trying to `group_by` and count the sum of the `DOLLARS.x` column but I am only getting 1 result when I want results for each `PANID`.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(datetime, PANID) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(DOLLARS.x))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1198584660, 1198584660, 
1198752840, 1199106060, 1198917840, 1199106060, 1198917840, 1198851120, 
1198758360, 1198758360, 1198925880, 1199091420, 1199091420, 1199091420, 
1198766040, 1198876140, 1198837140, 1198593480, 1198837140, 1198593480, 
1198837140, 1198593480, 1198837140, 1198593480, 1198662900, 1198662900, 
1198662900, 1198662900, 1199096220, 1199021400, 1198586880, 1199024280, 
1198586880, 1199024280, 1199017140, 1199017140, 1199017140, 1199017140, 
1199017140, 1199017140, 1199017140, 1198948620, 1198948620, 1198948620, 
1199102340, 1198663560, 1199011440, 1198745580, 1199011740, 1198770540, 
1199011740, 1198770540, 1198848900, 1198683660, 1198762320, 1198852800, 
1198767060, 1199112660, 1198595100, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198935780, 1198931940, 1198679760, 
1198671240, 1198942800, 1199115420, 1198751400, 1198849260, 1198588800, 
1199112300, 1199094960, 1199119860, 1198861260, 1199119860, 1198861260, 
1199119860, 1198861260, 1199119860, 1198861260, 1198763460, 1198942560, 
1198942560, 1198760460, 1199007120, 1199007120, 1198852920, 1198933500, 
1198674600, 1199119320, 1198936500, 1198770180, 1199109660, 1198919880, 
1198744560, 1199093820, 1199107080, 1198924500, 1198924500, 1198924500, 
1198924500, 1198832940, 1198832940, 1198858500, 1198941360, 1198745460, 
1198679280, 1198587240, 1198587240, 1198587240, 1199111880, 1198756560, 
1199018280, 1198850880, 1199002200, 1199002200, 1198846680, 1199091840, 
1199091840, 1199099940, 1199099940, 1198846740, 1198846740, 1198846740, 
1198840620, 1199107440, 1199107440, 1198580640, 1198761840, 1198580640, 
1198761840, 1199091600, 1199091600, 1198840140, 1198840140, 1198924020, 
1198844460, 1198779060, 1198779060, 1198859520, 1199100480, 1198599720, 
1198946220, 1198938480, 1198755000, 1199099400, 1198829520, 1198752480, 
1198923960, 1198754580, 1199102520, 1198667400, 1198576920, 1199011980, 
1199011980, 1198840200, 1198941420, 1198580100, 1199027040, 1199027040, 
1198840620, 1198745160, 1198836180, 1198592820, 1198603140, 1198592820, 
1198603140, 1199105340, 1199105340, 1198772760, 1198939440, 1198665240, 
1198864320, 1198665240, 1198864320, 1198665240, 1198864320, 1198665240, 
1198864320, 1198940520, 1198940520, 1198940520, 1199031120, 1198833960, 
1198833960, 1198579920, 1198745940, 1198749720, 1198836960, 1198758360, 
1198758360, 1198758360, 1198739220, 1198657200, 1198657200, 1198968360, 
1198968360, 1198968360, 1198968360, 1198968360, 1198846740, 1198846740, 
1198760100, 1198760100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), DOLLARS.x = c(9.98, 
4.28, 8.58, 1.49, 1.49, 2.19, 2.19, 2.39, 2.21, 0.88, 3, 2.79, 
5.58, 2.79, 2.21, 2.21, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 9.98, 9.98, 0.88, 
0.88, 0.88, 4.28, 4.29, 5.58, 2.29, 9, 21.3, 21.3, 13.48, 13.48, 
5.99, 5.99, 1.99, 0.88, 0.88, 4.99, 2.3, 2.68, 0.76, 1.98, 4.78, 
4.78, 20.22, 20.22, 2.5, 2.5, 0.88, 0.88, 2, 4.29, 9.94, 2.22, 
9.99, 9.99, 14.98, 6.36, 6.36, 6.36, 6.36, 6.36, 6.36, 3.33, 
3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 
3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 
2.98, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 
4.97, 4.97, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 2.99, 2.99, 2.99, 
2.99, 2.99, 2.99, 3.99, 3.99, 9.94, 3.99, 9.98, 1.69, 1.69, 4.99, 
4.99, 9.99, 9.99, 2.99, 2.99, 0.99, 9.39, 2.99, 10.11, 3.49, 
1.99, 2.5, 2.5, 4.28, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33, 0.99, 6.75, 0.88, 28.14, 
3.99, 0.99, 10.99, 3.99, 29.99, 4.99, 4.99, 9.94, 9.94, 4.42, 
4.28, 7.98, 3.98, 3.49, 9.99, 9.99, 5.78, 18, 8.99, 17.98, 9.99, 
4.29, 3.86, 3.5, 12.6, 0.99, 0.88, 1.59, 1.04, 3, 1.99, 4.99, 
4.99, 4.28, 4.28, 3.98, 5.49, 12.1, 12.1, 4.29, 4.29, 5.99, 2.99, 
8.58, 8.58, 8.58, 8.58, 2.99, 4.99, 9.98, 1.29, 1.29, 1.29, 18.88, 
18.88, 18.88, 2.5, 9.98, 4.28, 4.29, 2.39, 2.39, 12, 9.99, 21.98, 
21.98, 2.3, 2.09, 2.09, 4.99, 4.99, 1.99, 2.49, 1.19, 1.19, 3.18, 
3.18, 3.18, 3.18, 9.44, 9.44, 4.02, 4.02, 3.34, 4.99, 4.99, 2.36, 
0.88, 0.5, 3.49, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 12, 2.99, 3.98, 14.97, 3.33, 
3.33, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 5.5907348633, 3.29, 13.98, 3.29), 
    PANID = c(1101626L, 1101626L, 1104703L, 1104935L, 1104935L, 
    1104935L, 1104935L, 1105759L, 1106781L, 1106781L, 1110460L, 
    1114892L, 1114892L, 1114892L, 1116814L, 1116814L, 1120618L, 
    1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 
    1120618L, 1122242L, 1122242L, 1122242L, 1122242L, 1123752L, 
    1130930L, 1132282L, 1132282L, 1132282L, 1132282L, 1134692L, 
    1134692L, 1134692L, 1134692L, 1134692L, 1134692L, 1134692L, 
    1137273L, 1137273L, 1137273L, 1140707L, 1140707L, 1141721L, 
    1141721L, 1146563L, 1146563L, 1146563L, 1146563L, 1146894L, 
    1149815L, 1150359L, 1152744L, 1154153L, 1154153L, 1157727L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 1165944L, 
    1168278L, 1168278L, 1175109L, 1186346L, 1186544L, 1189423L, 
    1189423L, 1189423L, 1189423L, 1189423L, 1189423L, 1189423L, 
    1189423L, 1190660L, 1191957L, 1191957L, 1193169L, 1193169L, 
    1193169L, 1194654L, 1194654L, 1194837L, 1195057L, 1195057L, 
    1195057L, 1197236L, 1198119L, 1198325L, 1198366L, 1198739L, 
    1201616L, 1201616L, 1201616L, 1201616L, 1201988L, 1201988L, 
    1202507L, 1202507L, 1204461L, 1205252L, 1207191L, 1207191L, 
    1207191L, 1208058L, 1208058L, 1208520L, 1210161L, 1212340L, 
    1212340L, 1213439L, 1213819L, 1213819L, 1215178L, 1215178L, 
    1215251L, 1215251L, 1215251L, 1218149L, 1218602L, 1218602L, 
    1219154L, 1219154L, 1219154L, 1219154L, 1219295L, 1219295L, 
    1220178L, 1220178L, 1230318L, 1230318L, 1230813L, 1230813L, 
    1232256L, 1232256L, 1232256L, 1232256L, 1232611L, 1232611L, 
    1242875L, 1245944L, 1245944L, 1245944L, 1302935L, 1302935L, 
    1302935L, 1306506L, 1306654L, 1306654L, 1308130L, 1310698L, 
    1310698L, 1312843L, 1312843L, 1313114L, 1313114L, 1313114L, 
    1315101L, 1315101L, 1315101L, 1315101L, 1325753L, 1325753L, 
    1401836L, 1401836L, 1407148L, 1407148L, 1407148L, 1407148L, 
    1407148L, 1407148L, 1407148L, 1407148L, 1407783L, 1407783L, 
    1407783L, 1408252L, 1803494L, 1803494L, 1805721L, 1805721L, 
    1805721L, 1805721L, 1808550L, 1808550L, 1808550L, 1809269L, 
    1815027L, 1815027L, 3100347L, 3100347L, 3100347L, 3100347L, 
    3100347L, 3100545L, 3100545L, 3101105L, 3101105L)), row.names = c(NA, 
250L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I re-run your code and I seem to get expected result. What is the result you are getting ?

Comment: Start a fresh session and make sure you don't load `plyr` after you loaded `dplyr`.

Comment: The result I get is: `    total
1 4585114`

Comment: Check [Why does summarize or mutate not work with group_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp), [Why are my dplyr group_by & summarize not working properly? (name-collision with plyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with)

Comment: Re-loading R and unloading the ´plyr´ package seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Additonally, If you needed to keep `plyr` loaded, you could preface the `dplyr` functions with `dplyr::`, for example `dplyr::summarise()`. This tells R explicitly which package to use. In my experience, clashes between packages can sometimes be hard to identify except through experience.