# Is there a way to do the opposite of unnest_tokens? I want to combine words into a row based on a unique ID

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am currently trying to do some sentiment analysis and I want to revert each word back into its original format. So I want each word belonging to a unique ID to be combined in a single row. So I want the opposite of unnest_tokens function. I have tried the following:

```
dsWords <- dsWords %>% 
  group_by(IDReview) %>% 
  summarize(text = str_c(word, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However, I simply get all the words combined into 1 row, instead of a row for each unique ID. Can anyone help me out here? Below is a screenshot of what my data frame looks like and a subset of my data.

[image]

```
structure(list(IDReview = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    word = c("love", "love", "author", "side", "end", "show", 
    "one", "way", "think", "everyon", "also", "idea", "mani", 
    "amaz", "look", "mani", "idea", "think", "learn", "someth", 
    "dont", "know", "look", "fact", "see", "right", "dont", "write", 
    "review", "will", "hero", "will", "hes", "person", "tri", 
    "short", "certain", "never", "find", "like")), row.names = c("1", 
"1.1", "1.2", "1.4", "1.6", "1.13", "1.14", "1.15", "1.16", "1.17", 
"1.18", "1.19", "1.20", "1.24", "1.25", "1.27", "1.28", "1.30", 
"1.33", "1.34", "1.35", "1.36", "1.37", "1.38", "1.39", "1.41", 
"1.42", "1.44", "1.45", "2", "2.3", "2.5", "2.10", "2.12", "2.18", 
"2.23", "2.26", "2.27", "2.30", "2.34"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It should give a row for each `IDReview` (and it does on my machine). Are you sure you are using `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `summarize` functions? You can make sure this is the case by using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarize`.

Comment: @Bas Yeah, I guess that was the problem. it is working now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bas wrote in the comments, the following code with explicit package names

```
dsWords %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(IDReview) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(text = stringr::str_c(word, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

gives as output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  IDReview text                                                                                          
     <int> <chr>                                                                                         
1        1 love love author side end show one way think everyon also idea mani amaz look mani idea think~
2        2 will hero will hes person tri short certain never find like
```

That is what you intend, isn't it?

Note that there might be problems when you load `plyr` after `dplyr`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with).

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem indeed