# How to combine count() and group_by() to count responses with a certain value, grouped by respondent?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a set of data where the response to a series of repeated questions is the outcome of interest. Because of this, I'd like to count the number of "I don't know" responses, grouping those counts by respondent ID, and append it as a new column. So basically, I have data that look like this:

| ID | response |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 1 | I don't know |
| 2 | No |
| 2 | I don't know |

And I want them to look like this:

| ID | response | idkcount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | 1 |
| 1 | I don't know | 1 |
| 2 | No | 1 |
| 2 | I don't know | 1 |

This is the code I've most recently written:

```
df$idkcount <- group_by(as_tibble(df$ID)) %>% count(df$response == "I don't know")
```

But I seem to get an error message no matter what I try with these two commands. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `group_by` and `mutate` you could do:

Note: I slightly altered your example data to a more general case.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  response = c("Yes", "I don't know", "I don't know", "I don't know", "No", "I don't know")
)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(idkcount = sum(response == "I don't know", na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      ID response     idkcount
#>   <int> <chr>           <int>
#> 1     1 Yes                 3
#> 2     1 I don't know        3
#> 3     1 I don't know        3
#> 4     1 I don't know        3
#> 5     2 No                  1
#> 6     2 I don't know        1
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It seems like it should work, but for some reason the column it creates has populated entirely with the total # of 'I don't know' responses throughout the entire dataframe. Any ideas what might need tweaking with my data?

Comment: @nlplearner. Hm. Hard to tell what's going wrong. I just made edit and checked for a more general case. As you see the code should add a column with count of IDK responses per ID. But maybe I miss something about your desired result.

Comment: It's vary strange, I think maybe group_by() isn't working with my ID column for some reason? Your solution should work but the grouping isn't

Comment: Just to make sure: You use `sum(response ..` not `sum(df$response ...`?

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted the solution

Comment: One more question: Have you attached the `plyr` package besides `dplyr`?

Comment: You're problem is very weird but yeah I thought of that too, maybe the issue is that he didn't load the library(dplyr)

Comment: I just found a post mentioning the problem with loading plyr after dplyr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with Your solution works perfectly now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
my_df <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
                "response" = c("I don't know", "I don't know", "no", "I don't know", "maybe"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(count = length(which(response == "I don't know")))
```

Comment: This solution gives me the following error, do you know what I need to do to fix it? Error in FUN(left, right) : comparison of these types is not implemented

Comment: I could know if you tell me what is your dataframe and if you excatly copy pasted the code above or if you made any modfications

Comment: I copy/paste the exact code and my dataframe dimensions is 14496 x 9

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (I am using @stefan's dataset):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  response = c("Yes", "I don't know", "I don't know", "I don't know", "No", "I don't know")
)

df %>% 
  count(ID, response, name = "idkcount")

#>   ID     response idkcount
#> 1  1 I don't know        3
#> 2  1          Yes        1
#> 3  2 I don't know        1
#> 4  2           No        1
```

Comment: I get this error with your solution, do you know why? Error in count(., ID, response, name = "idkcount") : 
  unused argument (name = "idkcount")

Comment: Maybe, you have not installed `tidyverse`.