# Why is the average price not correctly grouping by room type in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have the following problem.
I would like the average price to appear for each room_type, however an equal value appears in all lines and the levels are still repeated in the table. It's as if the grouping didn't happen.

```
room_type <- c("Entire home/apt","Private room","Shared room","Hotel room","Entire home/apt",         "Private room","Shared room","Hotel room")

price <- c(100, 200, 50, 3000, 80, 90, 56, 30)

listing <- data.frame(room_type, price)
print(listing)



df_2 <- listing %>% 
  group_by(room_type) %>%
  mutate(price = mean(price)) %>%
  summarise(room_type = room_type, avg_price = price)
df_2
```

Comment: Instead of `mutate(price = mean(price))` pipe to `summarise(avg_price = mean(price))`.

Comment: Hi Rui. I already tried that way, but I keep getting 1 row with 1 column and 1 single value as a result :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. My comment asks you to run the code in [dandrews answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76290410/8245406), it works.

Comment: I already ran it, and it didn't work. It doesn't make the most sense, I know. I don't know if I'm missing any details.

Comment: it seems that the grouping does not work, something like that.

Comment: Close and restart the R session and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing this is another case where you have `plyr` loaded and there is conflict where you are inadvertently using `plyr::mutate` (which does not see groups) when you want `dplyr::mutate` (which does).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with

Comment: OMG!! That was the problem. Thank you very much! @JonSpring

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
listing %>% 
  group_by(room_type) %>% 
  summarise(avg_price=mean(price))
```

Here is the result

[image: # A tibble: 4 × 2 room_type avg_price 1 Entire home/apt 90 2 Hotel room 1515 3 Private room 145 4 Shared room 53]

Comment: You called `mutate()` before `summarise()` so you can just comment out that mutate call in your code

Comment: I had already tried this code and the result was not what I expected :(

Comment: Can you provide the expected output then? I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Karine I added a screenshot, is this not what you are getting as a result?

Comment: I was loading plyr before dplyr. This was causing all the trouble. Thank you very much for your try and help. :)

Comment: If you need both plyr and dplyr you can resolve by using dplyr::mutate()