# R: Mutate is not saving new variable / finding max date using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question about creating / saving a new variable using mutate in R.  In my data, I am trying to find the latest date by participant id and group.  Below is a sample dataframe.

```
id <- c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
time <- c (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
date <- c ("2010-01-01",  "2010-02-01",  "2010-03-01",  
           "2010-02-01",  "2010-03-01",  "2010-04-01",  
           "2010-03-01",  "2010-04-01",  "2010-05-01"  )
data <- data.frame(id, time, date)
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  select(id, time, date) %>%
  mutate(newdate = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(id, time) %>%
  summarize(max(newdate))
```

Here is what my output should look like.

```
id time date
1  1    2010-03-01
1  2    2010-04-01
1  3    2010-05-01
```

I keep getting an error stating that my new date variable, newdate, is not found.  I did some looking around at other posts and it seems like I am having a problem with mutate, specifically that the newly created variable, newdata, is not getting assigned to a new dataframe.  However, when I break apart this code, newdate is still showing up (see code below).

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  select(id, time, date) %>%
  mutate(newdate = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(id, time)
```

It seems like newdate is both being assigned to data2 yet is not being assigned to data2.

Alternatively, would it be easier to code this like this in base r?

Comment: This sounds like another instance where you have the `plyr` library loaded and are inadvertently using `plyr::mutate` and `plyr::summarize` instead of `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::summarize`. The plyr versions of those functions don't see groups.

Comment: Betting this is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with/26933112#26933112

Comment: Stack's tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please check the tags it recommends as being valid. The easiest way to do this is to mouse-over the tag and see what they say about themselves (tooltip). In this case, [tag:rstudio] clearly says *"DO NOT use this tag for general R programming problems"*, only for questions relating to the IDE itself; and [tag:tidyr] would be relevant if you were using any of its functions or needed to reshape/fill/clean-up the data, none of which is apparent in your question. I removed those and added the clearly-needed [tag:dplyr] tag.

Comment: You don't name your new column, so you get a frame where the third column is self-named as `\`max(newdate)\`` (backticks needed to treat it like the non-standard column name that it is). Use `summarize(date = max(newdate))` or `summarize(newdate = max(newdate))` or something so that the result is _named_.

Comment: @JonSpring, when I intentionally load `plyr` after `dplyr` and run this code, it works without error, it just ignores the grouping (since it's using `plyr`'s version of `mutate` and `summarize`). I don't know why it's producing that error (I cannot reproduce).

Comment: EricBoorman, try restarting R and making sure that you do not explicitly load `plyr` (to be sure it isn't the culprit), try your code again. I cannot reproduce this using R-4.3.1 and dplyr_1.1.2.

Comment: @JonSpring It looks like `plyr` was the problem.  Once I put in `dplyr::summarize` and `dplyr::mutate`, everything was running fine.

Comment: Glad problem is solved - as a general practice you will almost never need to load `plyr` nor use anything within it. The whole package is retired and replaced by others which keep up-to-date.