# Does `summarise()` preserve other unsummarized columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to follow this post https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/ggplot-error-bars/ to make a plot with error bars. However the summarize doesn't quite work. Why?

```
> df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)
> head(df, 3)
   len supp dose
1  4.2   VC  0.5
2 11.5   VC  0.5
3  7.3   VC  0.5
> df.summary <- df %>%
+     group_by(dose) %>%
+     summarise(
+         sd = sd(len, na.rm = TRUE),
+         len = mean(len)
+     )
> df.summary
        sd      len
1 7.649315 18.81333
```

But it looks like you should get something like:

```
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   dose     sd   len
##   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 0.5    4.50  10.6
## 2 1      4.42  19.7
## 3 2      3.77  26.1
```

Tried the first answer but still doesn't work

```
> df <- data.frame(len = runif(30, 4.2, 11.5), supp = "VC", dose = sample(c(.5, 1, 2), 30, replace = TRUE))
> df.summary <- df %>%
+     group_by(dose) %>%
+     summarise(
+         sd = sd(len, na.rm = TRUE),
+         len = mean(len)
+     )
> df.summary
        sd      len
1 2.385391 8.057899
> dput(df[1:10,])
structure(list(len = c(6.38568101720884, 9.66049139532261, 6.71973214379977, 
9.11211366723292, 10.07433216176, 8.6760600333102, 5.71324644873384, 
4.77394210803322, 10.921557949041, 4.29420428201556), supp = c("VC", 
"VC", "VC", "VC", "VC", "VC", "VC", "VC", "VC", "VC"), dose = c(2, 
1, 2, 0.5, 1, 2, 0.5, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Works for me on this example df: `df <- data.frame(len = runif(30, 4.2, 11.5), supp = "VC", dose = sample(c(.5, 1, 2), 30, replace = TRUE))`. Try your code on my example to see if it works. And if you run `dput(df[1:10,])` on your df and paste the results into your question, it'll make it easier to determine what your issue is. Ten rows might not be enough, but just make sure there's at least 1 of each dose type in your `dput()`. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting one row for each dose type on your `dput()` using your code. I tried it without running `as.factor()` on dose and it still worked. Only thing I can suggest is try clearing your environment, starting a new R session, or both.

Comment: You could also try `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` to see if you have more than one package with a `summarise()` function. You could edit your code to `dplyr::summarise()` to see if that helps.

Comment: Restart your R session, you are using functions from `plyr` instead of `dplyr` and do not load `plyr` or load it BEFORE loading `dplyr`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with/26933112#26933112

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you load essential libraries with `tidyverse`, and don't use `plyr` which is superceded. Like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# the df in your example
df %>%
       group_by(dose) %>%
       summarise(
             sd = sd(len, na.rm = TRUE),
            len = mean(len)
         )
#it gives
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   dose    sd   len
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.5  2.40  7.41
2   1    3.15  7.94
3   2    1.24  7.26
```