# How can I group variables in when dplyr and base R functions don't work?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I need to group my data for province IDs (MUN_RESID) and population (V16). My dataframe contains 8,627,071 observations. I've been trying solutions provided in this forum for days now such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653295/dplyr-issues-when-using-group-bymultiple-variables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923862/why-are-my-dplyr-group-by-summarize-not-working-properly-name-collision-with), but nothing works. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

This is what the sample looks like:

```
          X MUN_RESID   V16 X08.2005_P  X09.2005_P X10.2005_P
1             1    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
2             2    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
3             3    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
4             4    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
5             5    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
6             6    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
7             7    110001 13203          0 0.007574036          0
8627069 8627069    530010 14802          0 0.000000000          0
8627070 8627070    530010 14802          0 0.000000000          0
8627071 8627071    530010 14802          0 0.000000000          0


==X==============================================================X==
     Copy+Paste this part. (If on a Mac, it is already copied!)
==X==============================================================X==

 months0606 <- structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8627069L, 8627070L,8627071L),
          MUN_RESID = c(110001L, 110001L, 110001L,
          110001L,110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 530010L, 530010L, 530010L),
          V16 = c(13203L,13203L, 13203L, 13203L, 13203L, 13203L, 13203L, 14802L, 14802L,14802L),
          X08.2005_P = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          X09.2005_P = c(0.00757403620389305,0.00757403620389305,
          0.00757403620389305, 0.00757403620389305,0.00757403620389305,
          0.00757403620389305, 0.00757403620389305,0, 0, 0),
          X10.2005_P = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0)), class = "data.frame", row.names =
          c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8627069L, 8627070L, 8627071L))





==X==============================================================X==
```

I've tried

```
months0606_grouped <- ddply(months0606, .(V16))
```

(does not give me any output at all)

```
library(dplyr)
months0606 %>% group_by(MUN_RESID, V16)
months0606 %>% dplyr::group_by(MUN_RESID)
```

(does not give me any error warning, but does no grouping either. This is the output:

```
# A tibble: 8,627,071 x 20
# Groups:   MUN_RESID [5,227]
       X MUN_RESID   V16 X08.2005_P X09.2005_P X10.2005_P
   <int>     <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 2     2    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 3     3    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 4     4    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 5     5    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 6     6    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 7     7    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 8     8    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 9     9    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
 10    10    110001 13203          0    0.00757          0
# ... with 8,627,061 more rows, and 14 more variables:
#   X11.2005_P <dbl>, X12.2005_P <dbl>,
#   X01.2006_P <dbl>, X02.2006_P <dbl>,
#   X03.2006_P <dbl>, X04.2006_P <dbl>,
#   X05.2006_P <dbl>, X06.2006_P <dbl>,
#   X07.2006_P <dbl>, X08.2006_P <dbl>,
#   X09.2006_P <dbl>, X10.2006_P <dbl>,
#   X11.2006_P <dbl>, X12.2006_P <dbl>
```

Also tried:

```
months0606$V16 <- with(months0606, ifelse(V16 %in% months0606, "V16"))
```

My goal is to have my dataframe look like this: Every combination of MUN_RESID and population level(V16) only contains one row:

```
MUN_RESID   V16     X08.2005_P  X09.2005_P 
110001      13203   0           0.007507
530010      530010  0           0
```

Comment: Try `newdf<-months0606 %>% select(-X) %>% dplyr::group_by(MUN_RESID) %>% distinct() %>% ungroup()` or `newdf<-months0606 %>% dplyr::select(-X) %>% dplyr::group_by(MUN_RESID) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: The group_by worked - see output and how there are 5227 groups. Pipe to ```summarize()``` and choose a function like ```sum()```. If you need all columns summarized, use ```summarize_all()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for the unique rows of MUN_RESID and V16 - you can use the duplicated function

```
months0606[ !duplicated( months0606[ , c( "MUN_RESID","V16")]) , ]
```

since you are dealing with a large data set you could consider data.table but you need to decide what operations you are doing by your groups.  I took the means, in your example it matches the duplicated function, but wouldn't if there were differences in either of the X08 vars

```
library( data.table )
months0606 <- data.table( months0606 )
months0606[ , .( 
    X08.2005_P=mean(X08.2005_P),
    X09.2005_P=mean( X09.2005_P)
    ),
    by=c("MUN_RESID" ,  "V16" )]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew, Cole and A. Suliman. Your suggested codes worked well and are such a relief. This was my first question on SO and I'm so happy to have found such a great community helping out with problems. Won't be the last question I asked here, I'm afraid... Thanks!